# Can Hudson-CI pass tell ShellCommands where a build request came from?

Tags: hudson, jenkins

I would like to have Hudson do builds one way if they were triggered by a perforce submission (do a fast compile and link) and another way if requested from the Hudson http UI (build the project, all assets, and create an archive for testing.)

I've set up a ShellCommand to echo the entire contents of the system environment when two builds start (one triggered each way) and there is no useful difference between them.  Is there something in Hudson that I can leverage to make this distinction?  I REALLY don't want to have double the number of jobs in Hudson.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple options:

- [Parameterize the build](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build). Check *This build is parameterized* in the build configuration. Your build script can check for a default parameter value in the environment to do the quick build, and when building through the UI a user can choose to do a "full build."
- Use the [Release build plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Release+Plugin). Your full build sounds like a release to me.

Comment: +1.  Thanks, I'm going to take a crack at this on Monday morning.  I could probably do it now, but I'd have to VPN ALL THE WAY in to work!  =]